# Add typing to rest operator

Tags: typescript

Take this example with a rest operator :

```
type Foo = { foo1: string, foo2: number };

const { yeah, ...foo }: { yeah: string, [k: string]: any } = { yeah: '', foo1: '', foo2: 0 };
```

How can I specify the typing of my foo object better than with `{[k: string]: any}` and using my `Foo` type  ?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKAzBBGAXFAZ2ACcBLAOwHMAaTBAJn3IFcBbAIwmKgF8BuALAAoYQGM45ImiggIAQwAWtAHSqsiHvnSzF%20ImSq0A2gGs9JCpQC6%20OeRC9k0nQvwByN7XV4oHrw3wABl5BISA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define an intersection type:

```
type Foo = { foo1: string, foo2: number };

const { yeah, ...foo }: { yeah: string} & Foo = { yeah: '', foo1: '', foo2: 0 };
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKAzBBGAXFAZ2ACcBLAOwHMAaTBAJn3IFcBbAIwmKgF8BuALAAoYQGM45ImiggIAQwAWtAHSqsiHvnSzF+ImSo8oAMlgJk0nQvwByG7XV4odhw3wAGXoKFA)